# SQL Server Conversion failed when converting date and /or time from character string

Tags: c#, sql-server

I got a c# code which is supposed to insert records to a table and some of the columns are datetime.

I get the columns names and values from a file with everything hard coded inside which looks something like this:

```
"Columns": ["column1", "column2"],
"Data": ["Val1", "Val2"]
```

I'm creating an INSERT query with the data from the file.

The problem is that since everything is hard coded as a string in the file, I can't know when I should use `DateTime.Parse` in order to turn the string into a `DateTime`. For example, should I do this `command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameters[i], singleValues[i]);` or should I do this `command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameters[i], DateTime.Parse(singleValues[i]));`

Is there some way I can avoid checking the hard coded name of the parameter? The values of the strings which are date looks like this: "2020-05-11 11:58:00.100"

Comment: *Is there some way I can avoid checking the hard coded name of the parameter?* ... yes, `DateTime.TryParse` all columns :D

Comment: ... or obviously pass  `, "Types" : ["whatever", "datetime"]` .. and parse only columns with given type

Comment: @Selvin If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2):

`2020-05-11 11:58:00.100` is *not* an unambiguous date value in SQL Server. For the older date and time data types the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.nnn` can be read as `yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss`, depending on the language settings of the `LOGIN` you are using (basically if you aren't American). The *only* unambiguous formats are `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss(.nnnnnnn)` and `yyyyMMdd` regardless of datatype and language settings.

But, you are also making another mistake, using `AddWithValue`. Stop using that and pass your data with `Parameters.Add` and define the data type there. For example

```
command.Parameters.Add(parameters[i], SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Parse(singleValues[i]);
```

Comment: but the problem is that i don't know the specific parameter and if it should be a date time. Of course I can check it with "if parameters[i] == ... " but I'm trying to avoid that

Comment: But you *do*. If you check the name of the column first, which is related to the value, @YonatanNir , you know the data type, because you know your datatypes for the destination column in SQL Server for that column (in the source data).